# Is the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(i)^n}{n}$ convergent or divergent

Tags: complex-analysis

Does the series
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(i)^n}{n}$$
converge or diverge? The only theorems I've covered thus far are:

Theorem: A series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (x_n+i y_n)$ converges if and only if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty y_n$ converge.

Theorem: If $\sum_{n=1}^\infty z_n$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty w_n$ converge, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}z_n=0$.

Theorem: If $\sum_{n=1}^\infty z_n$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty w_n$ converge, then
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty cz_n=c\sum_{n=1}^\infty z_n$$
and 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty(z_n+w_n)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty z_n+\sum_{n=1}^\infty w_n$$
Theorem: The comparison test.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you know that the alternating harmonic series converges?  Look at the real and imaginary parts of this series.

Answer (score 4):

We can write

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{2N} \frac{i^n}{n}&=\sum_{n=1}^{2N} \frac{\left(e^{i\pi/2}\right)^n}{n}\\\\
&=\underbrace{\sum_{n=1}^{2N} \frac{\cos(n\pi/2)}{n}}_{\text{All of the odd terms are zero}}+i \underbrace{\sum_{n=1}^{2N} \frac{\sin(n\pi/2)}{n}}_{\text{All of the even terms are zero}}\\\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{(-1)^n}{2n}+i \sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{2n-1}\\\\
\end{align}$$

Now apply [Leibniz's Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test).

Comment: Hi Claude!  How are you my friend?  I don't answer many questions on MSE anymore because site contents have changed and there are few of the types of questions posted now that I enjoy answering.

Comment: Good to hear from you ! I agree with you :may be, I am now too old. I still have some fun. Cheers :-)

Comment: Sure.  Occasionally I will find a question that I feel I can answer well and add value to the OP and possible future readers.

Answer (score 3):

$$\begin{align}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(i)^n}{n}&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(i)^{2n}}{2n}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(i)^{2n+1}}{2n+1} \\ & =\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{2n}+i\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1} \\ \end{align}$$

Now apply Leibnitz test for alternating series.

Comment: How is this different from mine?

Answer (score 1):

$x_n$ and $y_n$ are alternating, decreasing series (since $i^n$ cycles through $i,-1,-i,1$).

By the Leibniz test they both converge.